# What's the deal with these two "tips for creating a golfing language" questions?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, languages, tips

We currently have two questions asking for tips about golfing languages:

- [Tips for making a golfing language](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/118107/tips-for-making-a-golfing-language) (posted in 2017) is closed for lack of focus, with +10/-3 and no answers
- [Tips for Creating/Maintaining a Golfing Language](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/198446/tips-for-creating-maintaining-a-golfing-language) (posted in 2020) is open and much better received, with +37/0 and 8 answers

Why did this happen, and what should we do about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Don't do anything

The first was closed because it doesn't come anywhere near close enough to the standards we require on a question's scope. It asks 4 questions at once, and answers could literally be anything that might constitute golfing advice. In particular,

> Do you have any suggestions for this language?

and

> What features do you find useful?

are blatantly not part of a question we allow here, as they're entirely subjective.

The second one is a much better version of this question. It's still rather broad, and it overlaps somewhat with [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14927/66833) question about community engagement. However, it asks for tips in designing a language to be good at code golf, as well as tips for actually implementing that. Additionally, it mainly asks for advice around generally creating a language, rather than specific features that would do well in a golfing language, meaning that [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6905/66833) precedent doesn't apply here.

It's not too unusual for older, lower quality questions to be re-asked as an improved challenge. This is yet another example, just as a [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips) question, rather than a challenge.

I don't have anything against closing the older one as a dupe, but given that it's low visibility, already closed and inactive, what's the point?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion:

- the second question is better specified, but is even less focussed
- in actual fact, neither of them are too un-focussed to be problematic (they're [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips), which is inherently quite open-ended)
- the questions are nevertheless similar enough to warrant closing one as a duplicate of the other

  - since the second is better specified and has some answers already, it should be the target and the first one should be the duplicate
- the best course of action is therefore to close the first as a duplicate of the second